# Installing imagescanner module in Python3.4 on Windows

Tags: python, image-scanner

I want to use [imagescanner](https://code.google.com/p/imagescanner/wiki/GettingStarted) module . I work with Python 3.4 . When I try this command in cmd : `pip install imagescanner`, I have got a message as you see in the picture :

[image]

so what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to this website ([link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/imagescanner))
2. Download ( imagescanner-0.9.tar.gz (md5) )
3. Extract the fails
4. open CMD
5. write "cd C:\Users\User\Downloads\imagescanner-0.9\"
6. write "setup.py install"
7. Wait until the installation complete
8. Close CMD
9. now you can use the module ;)

Comment: Yes that is worked . thank u . But step 6 is like : `python setup.py install`.