# Using ImageScanner Module with Python 3.4 on Windows

Tags: python, image-scanner

I have installed [imagescanner module](https://code.google.com/p/imagescanner/wiki/GettingStarted) on windows following this [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779465/installing-imagescanner-module-in-python3-4-on-windows/34779784#34779784) . I have connected to scanner on wifi . When I try this code :

```
from imagescanner import ImageScanner
iscanner = ImageScanner()
scanners = iscanner.list_scanners()
print(scanners[0])
```

an error message occured :

```
C:\Python3.4\python.exe C:/Users/PB/PycharmProjects/ImageScanner/deneme.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/PB/PycharmProjects/ImageScanner/deneme.py", line 4, in    <module>
from imagescanner import ImageScanner
File "C:\Python3.4\lib\site-packages\imagescanner-0.9-py3.4.egg\imagescanner\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from imagescanner.core._imagescanner import ImageScanner
File "C:\Python3.4\lib\site-packages\imagescanner-0.9-py3.4.egg\imagescanner\core\_imagescanner.py", line 61
except Exception, exc:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, imagescanner isn't compatible with Python 3.

You can try to fix it. The SyntaxError refers to the old syntax for exceptions ("class, variable" become "class as variable" in newer versions). But I'm not sure what other problems you can find.